# How can change UI text by mouse-click on an object in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton, uitextfield, onmouseclick

I have an object in Unity (cube) which its material changes with mouse click. I want to show information about each material in a UI text. So, the information needs to be changed. I have written the following script and it works when I assign it to a UI button. It means that my text is changed when I click on the button. But when I assign it to the cube, my text isn’t changed by mouse click. I would appreciate it if you could answer my question.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class CubeText : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Text changingText;
   private int i = 0;

   public void textChange()
   {

       {

       switch (i)
       {
           case 0:
               changingText.text = "Parket...";
               break;
           case 1:
               changingText.text = "Kashi...!";
               break;
           case 2:
               changingText.text = "Seramic...!";
               break;
       }
       i++;
       i = i % 3;         
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying when this script is on a button and you assign the `onClick` to this button, the code works. But you intend for this to not run on a UI button, but to run when the user clicks a 3D cube in your scene?

Comment: Use `Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition, ...)` if you know how to use raycast, then you should use ScreenPointToRay or something like that. Just look up the terms and you should be able to detect if the player clicks in the object, then you can change the variable in the switch statement.